# How Can I fix An Access 2010 "You Can't go to specified record" Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have inherited an Access 2010 Database and have a problem with a form that stopped working after the backend was migrated to SQL server.

The form is pretty simple it is a subform that opens and shows a grid for comments that have been entered. There is a "Add New" button on the form that should allow the user to insert a new comment. the code for that button looks like this:

```
Private Sub cmd_new_comment_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmd_new_comment_Click

DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
DoCmd.GoToControl ("com_date")
Me.ActiveControl = Now()
DoCmd.GoToControl ("com_comments")

Exit_cmd_new_comment_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_cmd_new_comment_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_cmd_new_comment_Click

End Sub
```

When I click the "Add New" button I get the Error Message "You Can't go the the specified record".

I believe the data is not the problem because when I open the comments form I can see all the previous comments it is only an issue when I want to add a new comment.

Comment: When you say a Subform that "opens", this implies that it isn't actually a sub form but a pop up form? If it is then I suspect it's being opened filtered to the main record by the parent ID field from the calling form. If it really is a sub form it sounds as if the Parent/child relationship is broken in some weird way, or the subform isn't set up to allow additions?

Comment: I am sorry Minty and must apologize.  I misspoke the form is not a sub form it is stand alone form that opens as a pop up.  The form is set to allow additions.

Comment: To be honest the simplest route would be to make it a sub form. Then the parent ID would default to the correct one and additions would be simple. You can always hide / show the sub form based on your button press.

Answer (score 0):

was the PK field in the Access table type autoNumber?  If so, you'll need to set up an identity specification in the design of the table on the SQL Server.

Comment: Actually the Access table did not have a primary key at all.  I tried to add a primary key to the SQL table but that did not help??

Comment: So when you started, there was no PK on the SQL side?  Can you add a new comment through the subform's recordsource?  Can you add other data on the server?

Comment: I got the form to work and this is what I did.  I added a primary key to the table.  Then recreated the form and used it as a sub form.  It is now working.  Thanks for all the suggestions.